# Quick and easy client for testing WSRP?

Tags: websphere-portal, jsr168, wsrp

I am writing a JSR-168 Portlet to be exposed as a service via WSRP on the WebSphere Portal Server... is there a good tool I could use to test the WSRP service on my desktop? I'm looking for something that would be considerably less hassle than installing Sharepoint and getting its WSRP module to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Pluto, or Sun's reference portal would be the most lightweight containers to test things out locally. Here is an introduction:
http://developers.sun.com/portalserver/reference/techart/openportal_wsrp.html

You can also download Liferay, a full-featured open source portal which has easy WSRP configuration and is less of a hassle to get running than Sharepoint. For more technical testing, I would use SoapUI and test the individual service calls. Something I probably need to write a blog post about one day ;)

Comment: Soap UI has been pretty helpful in this regard. I didn't realize Pluto could support WSRP.